# Connection to Access 2013 database with VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6, vba

I am trying to connect to an Access database 2013 (.accdb) from VB6, and keep getting errors. My code is as follows:

```
Dim db_file As String
Dim statement As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

' Get the data.
db_file = App.Path
If Right$(db_file, 1) <> "\" Then db_file = db_file & "\"
db_file = db_file & "FluidFlo.accdb"

' Open a connection.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & db_file & ";" & "Persist Security Info=False"
conn.Open '(PROBLEM IS HERE)

' Select the data.
statement = "SELECT strEmpName FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY strEmpName"

' Get the records.
Set rs = conn.Execute(statement, , adCmdText)

' Load the results into the ComboBox
Do Until rs.EOF
    cboUsername.AddItem rs!strEmpName
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
' Close the recordset and connection.
rs.Close
conn.Close
```

I am trying to load a table in to a combobox in the program, and assuming my connection string is having an error. I changed the `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;` and still no luck. Keep getting an error.

Does anyone have an idea of how to connect to an .accdb database, whether SQL commands or any? Thanks in advance...(pulling my hair out...)

Comment: Error states: Error 3706. Provider can not be found...

Comment: Is 32 bit Ms Office installed on that machine?  If not, have you installed the 32 bit version of the ACE driver?

Comment: Its x86-x64 so I'm guessing it's 64 bit...and no I haven't installed the 32 bit version of the ACE driver. Am I able to install it on a 64 bit laptop?

Comment: VB6 can not use the 64 bit version of the ACE provider, which yours is because it came with 64 bit Office.  I don't know how to install the 32 bit ACE driver on a system which already has the 64 bit version.

Comment: You haven't included a complete procedure. By chance do you also have an `On Error Resume Next` in there?  If so, remove it.  Also if you don't have `Option Explicit` as the first line in the module, I'd suggest adding that too. One or both of those could have helped you find what I think is a typo:  Unless you have `App` declared, I think the filename you're using doesn't have a path attached. Perhaps `Application.Path` would work better.  Check the filename `db_file` before opening it with the connection string.

Comment: I downloaded the 32 bit ACE driver and it all works now! Thank you all!

Comment: I have the Option Explicit as the first line, with no error traps

Comment: One thing to keep in mind for future reference is that ADO has an `Errors` collection object. The `Err` object only has the last error that occurred when performing an ADO operation. Since there can be any number of errors prior to the last one, you can often iterate the `Errors` collection to get a clearer picture of what is going wrong.